# Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
<?php``
if(mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))
echo"connect";
else 
echo "not connect";
?>
```

this is my code but it's not connected . give the error as warning

Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:..\pro1.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=2296 in C:..\pro1.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:..\pro1.php on line 2
not connect

Comment: you have to check some tutorials how to connect with database, here is a link which you can get little help http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp search google for  tutorials and mysql is deprecated so use mysqli or pdo for database connections

Comment: Interestingly enough, you have tagged `mysqli` but are not using using it.   Hmmm,  might this be a better way? ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using either `MySQLi` or `PDO` and their prepared statement to be more secure.

If you intend using just MySQL then use the below code to initialize your Database connection.

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

For reference see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Alternatively kindly use MySQLi

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

For reference see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

If you consider using PDO then try

```
<?php
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

For reference see http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

remove '' after  php open tag and 
try like this

```
  <?php
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 if (!$link) {
 die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname');   //your database name
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```