# MySQLi not able to select database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am stuck with a website trying to select a new database. In earlier scripts it all went fine and I was able to select databases and use them for my queries. This time however it won't allow me to change the database and stays on the previous one. This line does not work:

```
global $mysqli; 
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "new_database") or die("can't find it");
```

It simply stays with the earlier selected database...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you show the whole connection code..

Comment: Can you show your full connection script so we can be sure you are doing the right thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050505/warning-mysql-connect-error-while-reading-greeting-packet/30050759#30050759 in case you need to do your connection again

Comment: submit your full code. Where you set the value of $mysqli

Comment: This is how I connect to the database: [$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
GLOBAL $mysqli;]

Comment: Nevermind, the issue has been resolved. My access to the newly defined database was denied. I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

What's `$mysqli` here?
never mind that...you should try this:(although save this file in the include folder so you can `include()` or `require()` it on another file)

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db_name");  //localhost is the host name it could be your websites name,root is the user name,password is the password of the mysql and db_name is the name of the database
```

[this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) article will help you with `mysqli`.